# Does Flutter have a type of interface/adapter class for pages?

Tags: flutter, dart

Right now I have a landing page that has a bunch of links to different categories. These links will go to a bunch of pages that will have similar layouts, but the only difference is the text content of each page. Is there a way to make a page interface for these type of pages and reuse that code or do i have to make say 20 different pages? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple with Flutter, you can literally make a new StatefulWidget with your repetitive parameters (let's just said a Title and a Content):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String content;

  CustomPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.content,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomPageState createState() => _CustomPageState();
}

class _CustomPageState extends State<CustomPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: widget.title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Text(
            widget.content,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, in order to use it, you call the new Widget anywhere:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPage(
      title: "First Title",
      content: "Long long content: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    );
}
```

Your final result would be something like this:

[image: Repetitive Screen]

Comment: @JacobBarcelona my pleasure :) don't forget to mark my answer as correct so more people can search this and get it first.